# This code is running. And I can't figure out why? P:)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python programming

I want to quit the code and exit the execution when I type 'quit'

```py
prompt = "\nPlease enter the name of the city you have visited."
prompt += "\nEnter 'quit' when you're finished."

n = 1

while n <= 4 & True:

    city = input(prompt)

    if city == 'quit':
        break
    else:
        print(f"\nI'd love to go to {city.title()}!")
    n = n + 2
```

Comment: `&` must be `and`.

Comment: Note that `x` and `x and True` are equivalent.

Comment: `&` is bitwise `and` in python.  `4 & True` is the same as `4 & 1` which is 0

Comment: _This code is running in VSCode. And I can't figure out why?_ why **what**?

Comment: can you provide what the code is doing now on typing quit?

Comment: what is wrong with using a debugger and print statements to find out why the program is behaving how it does, most likely the programmer has made a mistake and you learn the most finding the error yourself, yes it sometimes involves a lot of reading and trieal and error

Answer (score -1):

It should be `and` instead of `&` and the code works because `city=='quit'` becomes True and you break out of the while loop.